# Deploying Laravel Over FTP

Tags: php, deployment, laravel, ftp, hosting

I am working on deploying a Laravel app to a bluehost server and I am running into some trouble.

Currently, I uploaded all of the Laravel files to the root of the server, then uploaded the contents of the "public" folder to the "public_html" folder. From here I opened the "bootstrap/paths.php" file and changed the public path to

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public_html',
```

After this, I am still unable to get content to display. Am I missing something? It looks like bluehost is running PHP 5.4.24.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: The error log shows

[09-Apr-2014 09:04:02] PHP Fatal error:  require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '**DIR**/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home1/regmuel/public_html/index.php on line 21

Could anyone help me figure this error out. I can clearly see what the problem is, I'm just not sure how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Maybe you have to switch to product environment? (Just a guess, I know laravel is a bit like Symfony2..)

Comment: Maybe composer update , when you got other bundles?

Comment: When you are using less, you have to compile the less files! they wont get compiled automatically.

Comment: @Xatenev what's with the LESS files now? Why composer update? what are you saying?...

Comment: Well, .less files have to be translated into CSS, but they won't automatically get compiled, you have to use <code>lessc directory/* > css/single.css </code> for example, or some kind of less file watcher. Or in Symfony2 for example, you can use assetic:dump console command

Comment: https://medium.com/laravel-4/3bed5d0e645e maybe check this tutorial -> its about deploying a laravel 4 project

Comment: I'm not using LESS at all, not sure what that has to do with it. Composer update shouldn't be necessary, I haven't added any dependencies since I was working on it locally.

Comment: From the error log....."PHP Fatal error:  require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home1/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `__DIR__` isn't getting parsed, are you sure your host isn't running PHP 5.2.* if you run `phpinfo()` on your host what version does it give?

`__DIR__` is only available from PHP 5.3.0 onwards

Comment: Under 'General Server Information' on the left of the CPanel - it says PHP Version: 5.4.24. I'll check with the host to be sure.

Comment: Yeah everything I'm seeing says that bluehost servers are running 5.4.*

Comment: Have you tried by uploading a file with `phpinfo();` in it and then browsing to that page?

Comment: Just did that. As it turns out it's running PHP 5.2.* VERY not happy with bluehost right now, as my own admin panel says 5.4.24

Answer (score 0):

RMcLeod's answer is perfect, just wanted to add to it something that I ran into with my web host *(specifically Bluehost)*. Even after the version of PHP running on the server was **5.4.40** (found using php -v via an `SSH` terminal), I was running into the same problem where it was picking up an older version of PHP when interpreting my `index.php` and wouldn't recognize the **DIR** constant.

I had to add the line

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php
```

to the top of the `.htaccess` file which is in the same folder as my `index.php`

Just for context, I was trying to set up my laravel 4.2 app on bluehost and it relies heavily on this constant.